# XML URL parsing error

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml file that I get by entering the url of that xml file as a parameter in my doInBackground function. Now I call this function 2 times.

During the first call it works fine.

During the second call it gives me a parsing error:

> 08-16 23:49:20.823  27735-28009/be.project.randomreader W/System.err﹕ org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT {"success":{"tot...@1:210 in java.io.InputStreamReader@9e143cb)

Does it have to do something with the "?" sign and the "=" sign in my url?

How can I change my code to resolve this problem?

```
   //first call: 
     ArrayList<String> url= new ArrayList<String>();
        url.add("http://api.theysaidso.com/qod.xml");
        url.add("");
        new DownloadXML().execute(url);

   //second call after a click event: 
    ArrayList<String> url= new ArrayList<String>();
    url.add("http://api.theysaidso.com/");
    url.add("qod?category=" + random);
    new DownloadXML().execute(url);

   private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>,Void,ArrayList> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... url) {

        try {

            ArrayList<String> urlLijst = url[0];
            String query = URLEncoder.encode(urlLijst.get(1), "utf-8");
            String url1 = urlLijst.get(0) + query;

            URL url2 = new URL(url1); //.toString()
            URLConnection conn = url2.openConnection();

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = documentBuilderFactor.get();
            DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = parser.parse(conn.getInputStream());
            parser.reset();

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("quotes");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("quote");
                Element quote = (Element) title.item(0);
                lijstQuotes.add(quote.getTextContent());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("author");
                Element author = (Element) title.item(0);
                lijstQuotes.add(author.getTextContent());
            }
      }
}
}
```

Comment: show the XML data you parse

Comment: http://api.theysaidso.com/qod.xml    : WORKS
http://api.theysaidso.com/qod?category=management   : DOESNT WORK

Comment: I can visit the page? EDITED my first call code btw

Comment: Added some of my code too

Comment: For this sort of thing you will find it much much easier to write a simple java class that parses the XML. Then you can run it and test it without a phone or emulator and all the complications of the android platform. Once you get it working. Plug it into do you background method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second call from

```
url.add("http://api.theysaidso.com/");
url.add("qod?category=" + random);
```

to

```
 url.add("http://api.theysaidso.com/qod.xml?category=" + random);
```

theysaidso API seems to change its encoding based on the headers sent or explicit format request. By appending .xml you are forcing the format to be xml. In the other case you are getting back a json response and the parser fails. More info here
    https://theysaidso.com/api

Answer (score 0):

In the first call your

```
url[0] = "http://api.theysaidso.com/qod.xml"
```

In the second just:

```
"http://api.theysaidso.com/"
```

So, you didn't get the XML second time.

Try to change

```
url.add("http://api.theysaidso.com/");
url.add("qod?category=" + random);
```

into

```
url.add("http://api.theysaidso.com/qod?category=" + random);
url.add("");
```

Comment: He still gives me a parsing error then. I splitted the link up in the first place, to try to avoid the error though... without success.

Comment: You can find out what in your url1, url2 and conn.getInputStream() just during debugging each time

Comment: the second call he gives me this: http://api.theysaidso.com/qod%3Fcategory%3Dinspire
for url1 and url2, so the encode function seems to have done it's job. Weird that the parsing doesn't work

Comment: You can add "InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());" before parse to look for the difference in InputStream